# How to use select and case in update statement SQL Server 2008 R2 without getting error

Tags: sql-server

I am using this query:

```
Use Database3

Update EmpItems 
Set ItGsKey = case 
                 when d.deCode = (select d.decode 
                                  from departments d 
                                  join employees em on DeKey = em.emDeKey) 
                     then (select gsKey 
                           from GLSub 
                           where gsAccount = (select d.decode 
                                              from departments d 
                                              join employees em on DeKey = em.emDeKey))
                    else ''
             end
from 
    EmpItems ei 
join 
    Employees em on ei.itemkey = em.emkey
join 
    departments d on d.dekey = em.emDeKey`
```

Please let me explain:

- Each Employee is linked to one department in the table departments
- Each Employee has multiple items and each item can be set with a GLSub (sub gl account)

The idea is:

To look in the employees table and get the department code (d.decode) linked to the employee and then use that code as the variable for the department and the subglaccount meaning:

John is linked to department 100 so the query should update the (ItGsKey = subglkey) with the subgl key that belongs to subgl account 100

My issue:

I get this error:

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

PS: If I use the query like this it works but then I have to enter 100 lines in the query.

Question is there a way to set the variable dynamically for each employee?

```
Use Databse3
Update EmpItems
Set ItGsKey = case when d.deCode = '100' then (select gsKey from GLSub where     gsAccount = '100')
               when d.deCode = '200' then (select gsKey from GLSub where     gsAccount = '200') 
          Else ''                                                          -    -> Use this if you should leave the non-valid SubGLs Empty/Blanks
          END from EmpItems ei join Employees em on ei.itemkey = em.emkey
 join departments d on d.dekey = em.emDeKey`
```

Any Help would be highly appreciated
Kind Regards
Theo

Comment: Marc_s Thank you very much for the help!! I tried to organize the code but  was not able to :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use SELECT TOP 1 gsKey on your query or change your query to this.

```
UPDATE EmpItems
SET ItGsKey = MD.gsKey  
FROM
(
    SELECT ei.itemkey as mainitemkey,
    (
        SELECT TOP 1 gl.gsKey
        FROM GLSub as gl
        WHERE gl.gsAccount = d.decode
    ) as gsKey
    FROM EmpItems ei
    JOIN employees em
    ON (ei.itemkey = em.emkey)
    JOIN departments d  
    ON (d.dekey = em.emDeKey)
 ) as MD
WHERE itemkey = MD.mainitemkey
```

Comment: Dear Jay, Thank you very much for your excellent answer and assistance!!! I appreciate a lot your help. May I ask two questions please:

Comment: May I ask two questions please:?  (1) when Jay say use SELECT TOP 1 gsKey do you mean? "then (SELECT TOP 1 gsKey from GLSub ....."?         (2) The query work perfect but I have an error "Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ItGsKey', table 'Payroll3.dbo.EmpItems'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.
The statement has been terminated."

Comment: One point I forgot to mention my apologies. Each employee-itm has GL accounts and SubGL accounts meaning glKey and gsKey, the query updates all items but it should update only if the employee-item has a glKey

Comment: Now the query looks like: (sorry it do not allow me to paste the query because too long) you know Newbie... :)

Comment: @Theo, join the employee item to gl accounts in the inner query on my example. That'll make sure that only employee items with gl accounts are updated.